# How to serialize GeoPoint using dart json_serializable package

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to filter my Firestore collections by distance using the following package.

https://github.com/fluttercommunity/firestore_helpers

Referring to their example they are using jaguar_serializer to convert the data received from Firestore to Location class. I have implement their getDataInArea function in my app but I am currently stuck because I am using json_serializable.

I have looked around and found that there is a suggestion on how to handle GeoPoint if using built_value at the following link.

https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/417#issuecomment-391661750

So I am wondering is there a way to implement something like what is shown in jaguar_serializer and built_value but using json_serializable package instead.

I am guessing that one way is to use `@JsonKey(fromJson: , toJson: )` but I am not too sure about how to get about doing it.

Answer (score 8):

The type returned from Firestore is a GeoPoint, you can just pass it through
using JsonConverter:

```
class GeoPointConverter
    implements JsonConverter<GeoPoint, GeoPoint> {
  const GeoPointConverter();

  @override
  GeoPoint fromJson(GeoPoint geoPoint) {
    return geoPoint;
  }

  @override
  GeoPoint toJson(GeoPoint geoPoint) =>
      geoPoint;
}
```

After that, annotate your parameter:
 `@GeoPointConverter() required GeoPoint location`

Comment: I recommend this answer. You can annotate the class with `@GeoPointConverter()` and all the properties will use that converter without having to annotate them in the constructor multiple times.

Answer (score 7):

After a bit more digging and trying to understand how things works. I have managed to solve my problem by writing the following in my class.

```
  @JsonKey(fromJson: _fromJsonGeoPoint, toJson: _toJsonGeoPoint)
  GeoPoint location;

  static GeoPoint _fromJsonGeoPoint(GeoPoint geoPoint) {
    return geoPoint;
  }

  static GeoPoint _toJsonGeoPoint(GeoPoint geoPoint) {
    return geoPoint;
  }
```

I guess the idea is just to not make any changes to the GeoPoint object. Anyway would love to hear it this is the right way or there is a better way of doing this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution didn't work for me. If you try for instance a jsonEncode on your object, it will fail. Other people feedback is welcomed. This is what I suggest:

```
@JsonKey(fromJson: _fromJsonGeoPoint, toJson: _toJsonGeoPoint)
GeoPoint position;
```

`static GeoPoint _fromJsonGeoPoint(GeoPoint geoPoint) { return geoPoint; }`

```
///A Map should be returned here to properly generate the json
static Map<String, dynamic> _toJsonGeoPoint(GeoPoint geoPoint) {
return {"latitude": geoPoint.latitude, "longitude":
geoPoint.longitude};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who still facing the issues should use the following Helper class Methods

```
  GeoPoint? fromJsonGeoPoint(Map<String,dynamic> geoPoint) {
return GeoPoint(geoPoint["latitude"]??0.0000,geoPoint["longitude"]??0.0000) ;
}

  GeoPoint? toJsonGeoPoint(GeoPoint? geoPoint) {
return geoPoint;
}
```

In your Model class just mark Annotators for `location` field.

```
@JsonKey(fromJson: fromJsonGeoPoint, toJson: toJsonGeoPoint)
GeoPoint location;
```

In `fromJsonGeoPoint` method it's nullable method and I used default values for `LAT` and `LONG` as `0.000`